# How to write Arabic Text in PDF using loaded font from FontFactory.register

Tags: java, utf-8, pdf-generation, itext, arabic

I need your help in writing the Arabic text in PDF. I have loaded the Arial font from the resources folder, but unfortunately the PDF is showing blank and no text is printed. So can you please help.

My code is as below:

```
FontFactory.register(System.getProperty("file.separator")+"resources"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"fonts"+System.getProperty("file.separator")+"arial.‌​ttf", "my_bold_font");

Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_bold_font");


PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell =new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("\u0625\u0644\u0649 \u0645\u0646 \u064a\u0647\u0645\u0647 \u0627\u0644\u0623\u0645\u0631",
                                           myBoldFont));
table.setRunDirection(PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL);
table.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
cell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
table.addCell(cell);
doc.add(table);
```

Comment: The font encoding must be IDENTITY_H.

Comment: @PauloSoares You mean that I should keep it like this: Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_bold_font", IDENTITY_H); ?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this. I am also stuck in the same problem.